# Vora Tools not connecting to Database

Tags: vora

We are receiving the following error when attempting to use the Vora Tools

> 2016-10-24 11:22:57.940907|-0400|DEBUG|handleConnect called|datatools|datatools.go:279
>   2016-10-24 11:22:57.941001|-0400|DEBUG|new database connection created: default localhost:49155|datatools|datatools.go:219
>   2016-10-24 11:22:57.941274|-0400|ERROR|error accessing database: default localhost:49155, dial tcp 127.0.0.1:49155: getsockopt: connection refused|datatools|datatools.go:163
>   2016-10-24 11:22:57.941310|-0400|DEBUG|disconnecting from database connection default localhost:49155|datatools|datatools.go:186

The Catalog seems to be running on port 49152, but we see no way of changing this port. Is there a way to force Tools to look for the other port?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Vora Tools connect to the Vora Thriftserver (in Vora 1.2 on port 49155). You should check if the Vora Thriftserver is running correctly. If not, the Vora Thriftserver log files should give some more information (/var/log/vora-thriftserver).

Comment: Vora Thriftserver shows as started but 49155 is not listed as an open port. the logs show no errors either, one log shows